# Subsetting two corresponding variables if both of them are true

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to create a vector with two columns that contain the following strings given that the data in BOTH columns are true. I tried, unsuccessfully with:

```
CrimesAndLocation <- table(c(Crimes_Data$Primary.Type=="ARSON","ASSAULT","BATTERY","BURGLARY","HOMICIDE","HUMAN TRAFFICKING","KIDNAPPING","ROBBERY",Crimes_Data$Location.Description=="RESIDENCE")))
```

I'm trying to get an output where:

- `Primary.Type`, is one of the 8 specific felonies listed above. Thus, it should not show all 32 possible felonies, just out of the 8 listed above
- `Location.Description`, is `RESIDENCE`

This is the goal of what I'm trying to do:

```
 COLUMN 1      COLUMN 2
"ARSON"      "RESIDENCE"
"KIDNAPPING" "RESIDENCE"
"BATTERY"    "RESIDENCE"
"HOMICIDE"   "RESIDENCE"
"ASSAULT"    "RESIDENCE"
...
```

UPDATE: `> str(Crimes_Data)` :

```r
'data.frame':   293036 obs. of  22 variables:
 $ ID                  : int  10248194 10251162 10248198 10248242 10248228 10248223 10248192 10248157 10249529 10252453 ...
 $ Case.Number         : Factor w/ 293015 levels "F218264","HA168845",..: 292354 292350 292363 292359 292368 292366 292351 292348 292364 292816 ...
 $ Date                : Factor w/ 124573 levels "01/01/2015 01:00:00 AM",..: 94544 94542 94539 94536 94535 94535 94535 94535 94529 94528 ...
 $ Block               : Factor w/ 27983 levels "0000X E 100TH PL",..: 13541 7650 22635 1317 13262 9623 12854 8232 24201 14279 ...
 $ IUCR                : Factor w/ 334 levels "0110","0130",..: 49 139 321 33 251 82 38 282 97 38 ...
 $ Primary.Type        : Factor w/ 32 levels "ARSON","ASSAULT",..: 3 7 24 3 18 31 3 13 17 3 ...
 $ Description         : Factor w/ 313 levels "$500 AND UNDER",..: 111 281 119 35 131 1 260 193 274 260 ...
 $ Location.Description: Factor w/ 121 levels "","ABANDONED BUILDING",..: 95 19 110 48 97 110 106 110 110 99 ...
 $ Arrest              : Factor w/ 2 levels "false","true": 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ Domestic            : Factor w/ 2 levels "false","true": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Beat                : int  835 333 733 634 1121 1432 1024 735 414 2535 ...
 $ District            : int  8 3 7 6 11 14 10 7 4 25 ...
 $ Ward                : int  18 5 6 21 27 1 22 17 7 26 ...
 $ Community.Area      : int  70 43 68 49 23 22 30 67 46 23 ...
 $ FBI.Code            : Factor w/ 26 levels "01A","01B","02",..: 11 17 26 6 21 8 11 25 9 11 ...
 $ X.Coordinate        : int  1154209 1190610 1172166 1176493 1153156 1159961 1154332 1163770 1193570 NA ...
 $ Y.Coordinate        : int  1852321 1856955 1858813 1841948 1904451 1915955 1887190 1857568 1852889 NA ...
 $ Year                : int  2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 ...
 $ Updated.On          : Factor w/ 442 levels "01/01/2015 12:39:07 PM",..: 288 288 288 288 288 288 288 288 288 288 ...
 $ Latitude            : num  41.8 41.8 41.8 41.7 41.9 ...
 $ Longitude           : num  -87.7 -87.6 -87.6 -87.6 -87.7 ...
 $ Location            : Factor w/ 173646 levels "","(41.644604096, -87.610728247)",..: 31318 40835 45858 15601 116871 140063 84837 42961 32176 1 ...
```

Comment: Would you be able to run `str(Crimes_Data)` and update the question to include this? Thanks

Comment: It's done.  What were you looking for in the str(Crimes_Data) function?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good job for the `dplyr` package. The `filter` function will filter a data frame according to any number of logical expressions that you feed it. The following should work for you:

```
library(dplyr)

filter(
    Crimes_Data,
    Primary.Type %in% c("ARSON", "ASSAULT", "BATTERY",
                        "BURGLARY", "HOMICIDE", "HUMAN TRAFFICKING",
                        "KIDNAPPING", "ROBBERY"),
    Location.Description == "RESIDENCE"
)
```

If you'd rather not use `dplyr`, you can do it the old fashioned way with base R, like this:

```
type.bool <- Crimes_Data$Primary.Type %in% c("ARSON", "ASSAULT", "BATTERY",
                                             "BURGLARY", "HOMICIDE",
                                             "HUMAN TRAFFICKING", "KIDNAPPING",
                                             "ROBBERY")
location.bool <- Crimes_Data$Location.Description == "RESIDENCE"
Crimes_Data[type.bool & location.bool, ]
```

Instead of an integer vector of indices, the `[` subsetting operator can take a boolean vector. In that case, it will only return the rows of the data frame for which the corresponding elements of the boolean vector are `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the `str()` aka "structure" output update, it makes it clearer to be able to help you.

To obtain a list of observations where

- these eight felonies : "ARSON","ASSAULT","BATTERY","BURGLARY","HOMICIDE","HUMAN TRAFFICKING","KIDNAPPING","ROBBERY"
- occurred at `RESIDENCE`

Try breaking up the task into slightly smaller parts:

Step 1:

```
ViolentCrimes = subset(Crimes_Data, Primary.Type ==  "ARSON" | Primary.Type == "ASSAULT" | Primary.Type == "BATTERY" | Primary.Type == "BURGLARY" | Primary.Type == "HOMICIDE" | Primary.Type == "HUMAN TRAFFICKING" | Primary.Type == "KIDNAPPING" | Primary.Type == "ROBBERY")
```

Step 2:

```
ViolentCrimesResidence = subset(ViolentCrimes, Location.Description == "RESIDENCE", select = c(Primary.Type, Location.Description))
```

Result:

`ViolentCrimesResidence` holds two columns with Column 1 being a list of Primary.Type and column 2 is Location.Description, where Column 1 only has values from the eight felonies of interest and column2 only "RESIDENCE"

### Explanation

Step 1:

From R website's examples about [`subset` and `OR` condition](http://rprogramming.net/subset-data-in-r/):

```r
PineTreeGrade3Data<-subset(StudentData, SchoolName=="Pine Tree Elementary" | Grade==3)
```

Whereas we have:

```r
ViolentCrimes = subset(Crimes_Data, Primary.Type ==  "ARSON" |
```

- we use the `subset()` function
- `Crimes_Data` is the existing data frame as input
- next are the conditions. Which simply take the pattern of VectorName == "Some string"`, in this case`Primary.Type == "ARSON"`
- But we want observations for the other types too, so use the "or" condition to include them
- in R, "or" is written with  `|` symbol. So we use this repeatedly to include each of the other felonies of interest
- the equal sign `=` is synonymous with `<-` and assigns, saves this subset result, into to a new data frame we call `ViolentCrimes`.
- note I prefer using `=` because it is less keystrokes to type than `<-`, either is correct

Step 2:

```r
ViolentCrimesResidence = subset(ViolentCrimes, Location.Description == "RESIDENCE", select = c(Primary.Type, Location.Description))
```

- the input is `ViolentCrimes` data frame we made previously which contains only the eight violent crimes , the eight felonies "ARSON", "ASSAULT"...
- now we are interested in, out of all these violent crimes, which ones occurred at home, so use condition `Location.Description == "RESIDENCE"`
- but a further option of `subset()` we didn't use before, is the `select = ...` option
- we do a `select = c(Variable1, Variable2)` to choose just the `Primary.Type` and `Location.Description` vectors
- note that if you actually don't want to limit to the columns aka Variables, you simply omit this `, select ...` option
- thus it saves this new subset into `ViolentCrimesResidence`

So, now in R when you:

```
ViolentCrimesResidence
```

You will see a two-column output you wanted of the eight felonies of interest, that happened in `RESIDENCE`.